# show and hide images on clicking the previous and next button

Tags: jquery, html

I have three divs div1, div2 and div3. Each div contains 3 images. The first image in div1 is set to active class by default. On clicking the next/previous link, the next/previous image must be set to active class and displayed. The already active class must be removed and hidden. The images in div2 and div3 also must be displayed. How to achieve this in jquery? Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite sure there are tons of examples out on Google.

Comment: I think you are looking for the '.toggleClass();' JQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

I think flickity comes to your help: http://flickity.metafizzy.co/